# Splitting ImageFolder into train and validation datasets

Tags: python, deep-learning, computer-vision, pytorch

I have loaded my dataset as follows :

```py
full_dataset = ImageFolder(root = os.path.join(root, 'train'), transform=train_transforms)
```

Now to split my dataset into training and validation sets, I used the following code :

```py
train_size = int(0.8 * len(full_dataset))
validation_size = len(full_dataset) - train_size
train_dataset, validation_dataset = random_split(full_dataset, [train_size, validation_size])
```

Both `train_dataset` and `validation_dataset` are of type : `torch.utils.data.dataset.Subset`. Is there any way to convert these datasets into `torchvision.datasets.folder.ImageFolder`. 
I need to do this as I am not able to iterate through datasets of type `torch.utils.data.dataset.Subset`

Comment: what do you mean by "unable to iterate ... `Subset`"? `ImageFolder` and `Subset` should be derived from the same super class and have very similar interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to iterate through a Subset just fine, since it has the `__getitem__` method implemented as you can see from the [source code](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/utils/data/dataset.html#Subset) :

```
class Subset(Dataset):
    r"""
    Subset of a dataset at specified indices.

    Arguments:
        dataset (Dataset): The whole Dataset
        indices (sequence): Indices in the whole set selected for subset
    """
    def __init__(self, dataset, indices):
        self.dataset = dataset
        self.indices = indices

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return self.dataset[self.indices[idx]]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.indices)
```

So the following should work:

```
for image, label in train_dataset:
    print(image, label)
```

Or you can create a Dataloader from a Subset:

```
train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size, shuffle)

for images, labels in train_dataloader:
    print(images, labels)
```

Same for `validation_dataset`.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I was able to create a DataLoader from the Subset.